# Is there a way to filter only one column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of dates, and a list of values. I am trying to get a neat list of just the first date that the value changes on, one under the other with no blank cells in between.

Here's an example:

```
Column A:
2023-05-01
2023-05-02
2023-05-03
2023-05-04
2023-05-06
2023-05-07
2023-05-08
2023-05-09
2023-05-10
2023-05-11
```

Column D:

```
19
19
19
20
20
20
20
21
21
21
```

This is how I want it to look:

```
2023-05-01
2023-05-04
2023-05-09
```

I've also attached a screenshot.

Currently, I have parsed through the data using `=IF(D3<>D2, A3, "")`, which has returned me the correct dates but with long stretches of blanks in between each date. I want each date to neatly sit under each other. When I try and filter, it filters the entire sheet. I don't know how to get these dates the way I need them.

[image: Here's the screenshot of a section of the sheet]

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=sortn(A2:A,9^9,2,D2:D,1)
```

[image]

`logic`: *uses [sortn](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) [display_ties_mode] = 2* ***Show at most the first n rows after removing duplicate rows.***

Comment: Is there a way to account for the year changing? The sortn function gets kind of wonky once I get 2024 dates in there

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.